# Windows Service cannot access file on UNC path (redux)

Tags: c, windows, service, windows-services, unc

I have a Windows Service (written in C running on Windows 10 x64) that needs to open (using `CreateFile`) and read a file on a UNC path, for example:
\\server1\share1\helloworld.txt

It is not on a domain.

I read a number of SO articles and the common suggestion seems to be to change the Log On for the Service to an account that has access to the UNC.  I tried that and still getting `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` from the CreateFile.

share1 gives Full Control to Everyone, and I can access it via Windows Explorer.

Is there a way to enable the Service to access files on the UNC path.

Comment: service this is passive component, he usually do something by user request. if service try open this path during user request - he must impersonate user. the unc is per logon luid mapped - this is because path visible only for concrete logon session. or if this not by user request - you must know user session for take it token

Comment: What user is the service running under? Some of the built-in users that many services run as don't have network access.

Comment: The Multiple UNC Provider (MUP) queries all providers (e.g. "LanmanWorkstation" for SMB shares) to determine which one claims the UNC path. If it's SMB, the connection to the server that's associated with a logon session might use credentials that aren't in the user's credential vault. Each time a user is logged on creates a new logon session, so just specifying the same user account isn't necessarily sufficient to use a connection that's associated with a particular logon session. It requires impersonating the client's access token, which is linked to the required logon session.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - the service is running under a Local Administrator account on the machine, which does have network access.